# How to make a 3-d filter with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am a high schooler taking ML at my local university and we are building cnn's using keras right now. I need to use a filter of size (32, 32, 3) but keras will only let me use 2D filters.

This is what I am trying:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (12, 12, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1,2)))
```

This is my error: "ValueError: The `kernel_size` argument must be a tuple of 2 integers. Received: (12, 12, 3"

Note: I am using the Cifar10 dataset.

Comment: Why you need 3d filters when 2d is enough?

Comment: @Amir Why are you assuming 2d is enough?? Some deep-learning for video inputs uses 3d convolutional layers with good reason (for instance).

Comment: They use 3D because videos are 3D if you include time. But images are not 3D and can't use 3D filters.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `Conv2D` layer of Keras when you should be using `Conv3D` layer.
Although, I think you are misunderstanding the concepts once your stride doesn't have a third dimension. In a 3D convolution operation, your kernel window must move in all 3 dimensions. Thus, your stride need to have the third dimension. The last dimension of `kernel_size` is always infered by the last dimension of the input size of the current layer.

So, in this code snippet of yours, if you want to use a 2D convolution, use `kernel_size = (12, 12)` and if your really want to use 3D convolution, define your stride parameter with a third dimension and use `3DConv` instead of `2DConv`.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! Someone was saying that keras will take care of my input depth of 3 (for rgb) and I can use Conv2d. But what you're saying is that if I want my lense to cover depth, I would need to make my stride paremeter 3D and use Conv3D.

Comment: The depth (as tensorflow calls it) is the channels, and it's the first argument of the `Conv2D`. It will automatically participate in your filters which will be `(size1,size2,in_channels, out_channels)`.

Comment: @Cameron Marcus Yes, the Conv2D will automatically cover all depth at once per unit of the output shape. It is confusing at beginning. One thing that helped me fully understand the convolution process in Neural networks was the animation in this [page](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv). Scroll down until you arrive the Convolution Demo part and check the math to get the correct shapes.

Comment: @CameronMarcus the previous mention was broke. I think you maybe not saw my last comment.